# how to display images correctly on mobile devices?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

[image: Mobile Image]

[image: Desktop browser Image]

The background image we have is 1920x1080p and it displays correctly on desktop browsers but not on mobile (not in portrait or landscape mode). Anyway to fix this issue? Do I need multiple images or there is a way to automatically resize? This is the .css file.

```
#tf-home{
    background: url(../images/OdysseyTitleImage.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    color: #cfcfcf;
}

#tf-home .overlay{
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.8) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.73) 17%, rgba(0,0,0,0.66) 35%, rgba(0,0,0,0.55) 62%, rgba(0,0,0,0.4) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.8)), color-stop(17%,rgba(0,0,0,0.73)), color-stop(35%,rgba(0,0,0,0.66)), color-stop(62%,rgba(0,0,0,0.55)), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,0,0,0.4))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.8) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.73) 17%,rgba(0,0,0,0.66) 35%,rgba(0,0,0,0.55) 62%,rgba(0,0,0,0.4) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.8) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.73) 17%,rgba(0,0,0,0.66) 35%,rgba(0,0,0,0.55) 62%,rgba(0,0,0,0.4) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.8) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.73) 17%,rgba(0,0,0,0.66) 35%,rgba(0,0,0,0.55) 62%,rgba(0,0,0,0.4) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(0,0,0,0.8) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.73) 17%,rgba(0,0,0,0.66) 35%,rgba(0,0,0,0.55) 62%,rgba(0,0,0,0.4) 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#cc000000', endColorstr='#66000000',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    height: 1080px;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
.home-lead{
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    background-color: rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.9);
    font-size: 21px;
}
.content{
    position: relative;
    padding: 30% 0 0;
}
```

This is the .html file

```
<div id="tf-home" class="text-center">
    <div class="overlay">
        <div class="content">
            <div><a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HRlP0t41wCw" class="btn tf-btn btn-default popup-video">Watch the trailer</a></div>
            <a href="#tf-game" class="fa fa-angle-down page-scroll"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Doesn't look like Android code to me - why'd I find this by searching for Android? I have nothing to offer. womp womp can't believe I've clicked another one.

Comment: Ok sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely caused by the `height: 1080px;` in `#tf-home .overlay`. It looks good on desktop because it had the necessary real estate for a large height. But the same height is also applied to mobile, so the graphic's area is much larger than the average mobile viewport.

Have you tried creating a more appropriate (smaller) height in a media query for mobile? Eg.

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
    #tf-home{
        background-attachment: scroll;
    }
    #tf-home .overlay {
        height: 320px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do I need to create a separate image and save it or this code automatically re-adjusts the size of a larger image?

Comment: I'd start by using the same image and see if you can manipulate it one way for desktop and another way for mobile. CSS is capable of resizing a desktop image down for smaller screens. Once you have the code displaying the image two different ways, you can create a second image that's optimized for mobile if the desktop one is not suitable. Your call.

Comment: It really does not work well for iphones for some reason. I tried using the code but still does not display image correctly.

Comment: The `background-attachment:fixed;` might be causing an issue as well. I've updated the code in my answer above.